# Problem when trying to rotate a 2D shape in a 3D space

Tags: c++, math, opengl, 3d, glm-math

i'm working on a batch renderer and i'm having trouble implementing a rotation feature for 2D shapes like a rectangle or a triangle. I'm using a Vertex* (struct Vertex code below) to store the position and color values, which works pretty well, until i got to rotations.

```
struct Vertex
{
    glm::vec3 position;
    glm::vec4 color;
};
```

I tried to make a mat4 and use the corresponding rotation function accordingly, which worked well when i set the model view projection in the shader, but converting the data to a Vertex wasn't working and very laggy. Therefore i thought i use some math that i found online, but my squares that i drew were streched to rectangles sometimes and the positions were off. I put in alot of hours now and tried different stuff, but nothing worked. That's why i hope someone can maybe find an obvious bug in my code or direct me to a good source where i can read about this topic (the stuff i found was either irrelevant for my purposes or hard to understand).

Here is my summarized code, i tried to keep it as short as possible:

```
void rotateX(float angle) 
{
    yr = yr * cos(angle) - zr * sin(angle);
    zr = zr * cos(angle) + yr * sin(angle);
}

void rotateY(float angle)
{
    xr = xr * cos(angle) - zr * sin(angle);
    zr = zr * cos(angle) + xr * sin(angle);
}

void rotateZ(float angle)
{
    xr = xr * cos(angle) - yr * sin(angle);
    yr = yr * cos(angle) + xr * sin(angle);
}

std::array<Vertex, 4> createQuad(glm::vec3 pos, glm::vec3 rotation, glm::vec4 rgba)
{
    float xr = 1.0f;
    float yr = 1.0f;
    float zr = 1.0f;

    rotateX(rotation.x);
    rotateY(rotation.y);
    rotateZ(rotation.z);

    Vertex v0;
    v0.position = glm::vec3(pos.x,      pos.y + yr, pos.z);
    v0.color = rgba;

    Vertex v1;
    v1.position = glm::vec3(pos.x + xr, pos.y + yr, pos.z);
    v1.color = rgba;

    Vertex v2;
    v2.position = glm::vec3(pos.x + xr, pos.y, pos.z + zr);
    v2.color = rgba;

    Vertex v3;
    v3.position = glm::vec3(pos.x,      pos.y, pos.z + zr);
    v3.color = rgba;

    return { v0, v1, v2, v3 };
}
```

Other notes:

1. When i remove the rotate()'s and the '+ yr' the code works fine.
   I'm not 100% sure about the '+ yr', but i don't know how to rotate around the y-axis then.
2. Accessing the elements of the mat4 with '[][]' wasn't giving me the right values and it was REALLY laggy for some reason. That's why i'm trying to avoid that if possible and go with raw math.

I'm going to bed for now, it's really late and i have a headache... hopefully my question wasn't too nooby or stupid, in that case i'm sorry for bothering you. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What do you want `createQuad` to do? Create a rectangle? Create a square? Do you want the created thing to be centered on `pos`, or have `pos` for one vertex or what? Do you have an example of the input you gave it and the output you wanted?

Comment: *"which worked well when i set the model view projection in the shader, but converting the data to a Vertex wasn't working [...]"* - Why do you want to do that? Where do you apply  the projection matrix? Why do you not just multiply the vector by the matrix?

Comment: @Beta, I want createQuad to create a square at the Position of glm::vec3 pos. The four "struct Vertex" i return can then be easily added to a Vertex*, which i give to the GPU via glBufferSubData. For now, i don't care if it rotates around the center or at one vertex. Inputs where mostly angles of 45 degrees for either the x, y or z axis, which however streched the square to a rectangle. In addition, rotation around the y-axis did not work at all. The output i want is a rotated square around the corresponding axises.

Comment: @Rabbid76 I wanted to get the data from the matrix, so i can create a "struct Vertex" with it. That way i can add them to my Vertex* and just send them to the GPU easily. I set the projection and view matrices in the shader, as they do not change. Later i want the positions of the vertices to change but still be batched, that's why i give them to the GPU directly. To change  a position before, i changed the matrices in the shader and did another draw call, which let to lag.

Comment: @jediknightcode I've not idea what you mean by *"I wanted to get the data from the matrix, so i can create a "struct Vertex" with it."*. Why do you want to do the model transformation on the CPU rather then the GPU? Anyway did you take care about the aspect ration (rectangular viewport) when you setup the projection matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, change your `rotate` functions to accept a vector as an argument, rather than apply the rotations to globals (or whatever those are).

Then instead of one vector:

```
r = {1, 1, 1}
```

use two:

```
r = {1, 0, 0}
s = {0, 1, 0}
```

Rotate them both (using the same angle arguments), then construct the square. (I don't know the syntax of a `glm::vec3`, but this is simple vector addition):

```
Vertex v0 = pos;

Vertex v1 = pos + r;

Vertex v2 = pos + r + s;

Vertex v3 = pos + s;
```

Comment: Thank you @Beta for your help, my understanding of rotation and my implementation was flawed. Your answer cleared this up very well! I also mixed up degrees and radians when giving this function it's rotation variable. Hope you have a nice day!